# How to use names instead of id's in dynamic webpages

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, html

I just started learning php and mysql and i might already be way ahead of myself. The thing i would like to create is a webpage where ppl can sign up for an event, so far so good, the form to submit their first name, last name, age and email adress is working and its actually sending te information to the database.

Next thing i want to create is a page where i can display all the database records submitted (except for the email adress). This is also working, but I wanted to play around with dynamic urls.

When i visit my page http://www.example.com/ppl.php?id=1 i get the information of the first database record displayed but i also wanted to see if i could get this to work with names instead of ids so i tried to edit my code and use http://www.example.com/ppl.php?name=john this does only return an error and however there are a few people called john in the database no records are displayed.

So i would like to know if what i want is actually possible and how do i get this to work with my current code.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "event";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $firstname = 'firstname';
    $lastname = 'lastname';
    $age = 'age';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = $id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo "<table id='display' width='600' align='center'>";
    echo"<tr><td>&nbsp;Firstname</td> <td>&nbsp;Lastname</td> <td>&nbsp;Age</td>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo"<tr><td width='33%'>&nbsp;$row[$firstname]</td> <td width='33%'>&nbsp;$row[$lastname]</td> <td width='33%'>&nbsp;$row[$age] cm</td></tr>";


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";

}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any code where you $_GET["name"] and query the name for the correct rows..?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = $id";
```

To:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'";
```

Then echo for each one John you find.

Also consider using CSS like this.

```
<style>
    #display {
        width: 600px;
    }
    #display td {
        width: 33%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Kostas! This was exactly what i needed =)

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for two separate `$_GET` keys: `id` OR `name`.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    // logic to get row by ID

} elseif (isset($_GET['name'])) {

    // logic to get row by Name

} else {

    // logic if no $_GET keys are set

}
```

I would recommend **not** using the `name` field for a find because it's not a primary key in your database - it may not be unique. Your query may return multiple results depending on what data is being stored.

**Edit**: To answer the question of *where* to place this in the code sample above, consider placing it where the query string is declared.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = $id";
} elseif (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name = '$name'";
}
```

From there you can keep the same query execution logic. But as I stated, I'd advise against using the `name` field as a key because it may not be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Just need to figure out where to put those lines in my code, but will definitly use this =)